# ResultSet takes RAM after closing

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, resultset, ram

I have problem with memory leaking.  This schemat of my code :

```
CallableStatement c = Baza.conn.prepareCall("select * from something");           
ResultSet rs = c.executeQuery();//takes about 100sec

while(rs.next())
{
//do stuff, only calculations, I don't create any object
}   

rs.close();
c.close();
```

While `executeQuery` is performing Ram usage goes up to 300MB and never goes down again. When program is in the same place again (but has slighty diffrent select) sometimes Ram usage goes up again and sometimes not.   Schould I to something more than just close `ResultSet` ? Help would be really appreciate because now I have to restart that program every few hours.

I am using JDBC4 and posgresql

Comment: what exactly are you measuring and on what operating systems? oracle JVMs tend to hold on to memory theyve allocated from the OS even if they dont need it any longer.

Comment: Use pagination in query

Comment: I am measuring ram usage in Windows Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cursor and set the fetch size to reduce your memory usage for the query.

```
Baza.conn.setAutoCommit(false); // Turn off autocommit on the connection to enable cursors in JDBC
CallableStatement c = Baza.conn.prepareCall("select * from something");           
c.setFetchSize(1000); // The fetch size determines the number of records returned in each "Batch"
ResultSet rs = c.executeQuery();// This may appear to run faster depending on the query

// Nothing changes here.  The JDBC driver handles the cursor for you.
while(rs.next())
{
//do stuff, only calculations, I don't create any object
}   

rs.close(); // This will close the cursor
c.close(); // I would recommend re-enabling autocommit if you weren't closing the connection here
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to close "conn" too.

The JVM manages memory internally.  You shouldn't necessarily expect the RAM utilization reported by your OS to be freed immediately.  It should eventually be released when the JVM performs a garbage collection.  Configure a JMX listener and use JConsole to monitor JVM memory,  and don't trust the OS.

Answer (score 0):

if the query takes that long it might either be that the connection is really slow, or u get back lots of data. holding all the data in RAM isn't the best solution. as the comment by Jigar Joshi already pointed out: you might wanna look into paging. also, it's good practice to close the connection as well. regarding the garbage collection consider Java7, it has a new garbage collector (e.g. see [Java 7 (JDK 7) garbage collection and documentation on G1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111310/java-7-jdk-7-garbage-collection-and-documentation) ) that might suit your needs better

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
Baza.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

before ResultSet, and use  :

```
rs.getMoreResults(java.sql.Statement.CLOSE_CURRENT_RESULT);
Baza.conn.commit();
```

after ResultSet and before

```
rs.close();
c.close();
```