# Java Heaps and GC on Multi-Processor machines?

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection, multiprocessing

How does Java deal with GC and Heap Allocation on multi-processor machines?

In the reading I've done, there doesn't seem to be any difference in the algorithms used between single and multi-processor systems. The art & science of GC tuning is Java seems fairly mature, yet I can't find anything related to this in any of the common JVM implementations.

As a data point, in .Net, the algorithm changes significantly: There's a heap affinitized to each processor, and each processor is responsible for that heap. This is documented in a number of places such as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx):

> Scalable Collections On a multiprocessor system running the server
>   version of the execution engine (MSCorSvr.dll), the managed heap is
>   split into several sections, one per CPU. When a collection is
>   initiated, the collector has one thread per CPU; all threads collect
>   their own sections simultaneously. The workstation version of the
>   execution engine (MSCorWks.dll) doesn't support this feature.

Any insight that can be offered into Java GC tuning specifically for multi processor systems is also of interest to me.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in Hotspot JVM, the way that the heap is used does not depend on the heap size or number of cores.

Each thread (not processor) has a Thread Local Allocation Buffer (TLAB) so that object allocation is cheap and thread-safe. This memory space is kind of identical to that heap-processor-affinity you are mentionning.

You can also activate Non-Uniform Memory Access (NUMA). The idea behind NUMA is to prefer the RAM that is close to a CPU chip to store objects instead of considering the entire heap as a uniform space.

Finally, the GC are multi-threaded and scale on your number of cores, so they take advantage of your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is an implementation specific concept. Different JVMs (IBM, Oracle, OpenJDK, etc.) have different implementations, and different mechanisms are available in different versions too. Often you can select which mechanism you want to use when you start your Java program.

[Similar questions here....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111310/java-7-jdk-7-garbage-collection-and-documentation)

These details are often given in the documentation for the commandline options for your JRE:

[IBM JDK Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.aix.70.doc/user/garbage.html)

[Oracle JRE Options here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf)

Comment: I've looked at the various JVM's and not seen any details around GC algorithms changing on multi-process systems. I was expecting to find expensive commercial implementations having such feaures, but instead I found... nothing.

Comment: One of the reasons may be because, thinking about it, *all* the GC policies I can think of are tailored to MP already.... Trying to find on that is designed for SingleProcessor would be more challenging (if you ignore dalvik).

Comment: ... but none of them do things like breaking up and affinitizing the heap to each available processor. I'm just surprised that I can't find any multi-processor specific into on Java Heap Management.